# JavaScript variable does not retain value across mouseDown() events

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a bit of a beginner, I started JavaScript around a week ago. I can't figure out what's wrong with my code.

my guess is it has something to do with the id and html but I could be wrong.

HTML:

```
<!-- imports font -->
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<!--Gets css and java files-->
<script src="js/Untitled2.js"></script>



<title>just click</title>

<html>
    <button onclick="mouseDown()">press</button>
    <p id='count'>0</p>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function mouseDown() {
    clickCount = clickCount + 1;
    document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = clickCount;   
}
```

Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are referencing clickCount before initializating it. One solution would be to declare it global starting with zero. Or getting the value every time you click, like this:

```
function mouseDown() { 
  count = document.getElementById('count').innerHTML
  clickCount = Number(count) + 1; 
  document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = clickCount;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I should also say that I've been taken an online course about JavaScript but they have been teaching me p5.js, so there is probably the reason I was having trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should make `clickCount` persist.

```
let clickCount = 0;
const mouseDown = () => {
  clickCount += 1;
  document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = clickCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1:

`clickCount = clickCount + 1;`  you can use `clickCount++`

2: `clickCount` was not defined

3: Check Arthur Pereira's answer it's good ( or Hyunwoong Kang )

4: how was that a week??? and "java" files you mean javascript?

Comment: Sorry for any confusion, I am a high school student and I try to do JavaScript any free time I get, but I have made other (much better)programs.